# Laying Out Content Horizontally with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am laying out content in a Bootstrap app. My content is laid out in rows. Currently, I have the following:

```
<div>
  <span class="badge">{{rowNumber}}</span>
  <a ng-repeat="item in items" style="display: inline-block; margin:4px padding:0px 8px;">
    {{item.name}}
  </a>
</div>
```

If my collection has 4 items, the items are laid out horizontally, aligned to the left. I need the ability to to lay out the items evenly across the full width of the available space.

How do I do this with CSS / Bootstrap?

Thank you!

Comment: Use flexbox?: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered this before but you didn't write a complete question. Your comment mentioned a fixed width first element and the rest of the content takes up the remaining space evenly.

[image]

### DEMO: http://jsbin.com/vebiy/1/

*http://jsbin.com/vebiy/1/edit?html,css,output*

**CSS**

```
.container-app .row {
   display:table;
   width:100%;
   margin:0;
}
.row > div {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display:table-cell;
    border-top:1px solid #ddd;
    padding:5px;
}
.container-app .row .badge {
    padding: 10px;
    width:100%;
}
.container-app .row div:first-child  {
    width: 150px;
    background:yellow;
    white-space:nowrap;
    position:relative;
}
.container-app .row div:first-child:before {
    content:'';
    width: 150px;
    display:block;
    height: 1px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.overflow-div {
    overflow:auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
    -ms-overflow-style:-ms-autohiding-scrollbar
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-app">
   <div class="overflow-div">
      <div class="row">
            <div>first fixed width</div>
            <div><span class="badge">Badge</span></div>
            <div><span class="badge">Badge</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
            <div>first fixed width</div>
            <div><span class="badge">Badge</span></div>
            <div><span class="badge">Badge</span></div>
            <div><span class="badge">Badge</span></div>
            <div><span class="badge">Badge</span></div>
            <div><span class="badge">Badge</span></div>
            <div><span class="badge">Badge</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
            <div>first fixed width</div>
            <div><span class="badge">Badge</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
            <div>first fixed width</div>
            <div><span class="badge">Badge</span></div>
            <div><span class="badge">Badge</span></div>
            <div><span class="badge">Badge</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
            <div>first fixed width</div>
            <div><span class="badge">Badge</span></div>
            <div><span class="badge">Badge</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
            <div>first fixed width</div>
            <div><span class="badge">Badge</span></div>
            <div><span class="badge">Badge</span></div>
            <div><span class="badge">Badge</span></div>
            <div><span class="badge">Badge</span></div>
            <div><span class="badge">Badge</span></div>
            <div><span class="badge">Badge</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
            <div>first fixed width</div>
            <div><span class="badge">Badge</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
            <div>first fixed width</div>
            <div><span class="badge">Badge</span></div>
            <div><span class="badge">Badge</span></div>
            <div><span class="badge">Badge</span></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you're going to use tables for layout, add [`role="presentation"`](http://juicystudio.com/article/layout_tables_repair_techniques.php)

Comment: I figured out a better way.

Comment: Haven't actually used a table since maybe 04 or something, so that was weird.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [Flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to achieve what you want. If I interpret your question correctly, what you want to do is to have each row dynamically distribute the space available space evenly to its children. If a row has two children (badge + one item), each child should have 50% of the available space, but if there are 10 children (badge + nine items), each should have only 10% of the available space. This jsfiddle shows you how to accomplish that using flexbox:

http://jsfiddle.net/renwfee1/2/

This is the structure:

```
<div class="a_row">
    <span class="badge">rowNumber 0</span>
    <div class="item">item 0</div>
    <div class="item">item 1</div>
    ...
    <div class="item">item n</div>
</div>
```

The important bits of css are:

```
.a_row {
    display: flex;
    ...
}

.item {
    text-align: center;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

The *display: flex* makes the row use flexbox for laying out its children, which lets you control how white space is distributed between children. This brings us on to *flex-grow: 1*, which instructs the browser that this item is willing to grow if it is in a flex parent and there is available space that was not claimed by other children naturally. We here give all children flex-grow "importance" of one (default is zero, don't grow), meaning that each child will get an even share of the available extra white space (if any).

If you do not want the children to automatically use all the available white space, you can remove the flex-grow property from them and add the following to the row:

```
.a_row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    ...
}
```

*justify-content: space-between* instructs the browser to put any available white space not used by it's children between the children. This is what that looks like:

http://jsfiddle.net/0unpfm5j/1/

If this solves your problem, I really encourage you to take a look at the [wonderful CSS Tricks article](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) that explains all the flexbox related properties and what they do.

Finally, note that I did not include any browser prefixes for the flexbox, which you should if you implement this live. CSS Tricks has [another nice article](http://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/) about how to get the vendor prefixes right, so have a look there as well.

Comment: +1 (earlier today) for a really good answer on flexbox. Copy this somewhere so you can use it again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into the [bootstrap grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), as this is exactly what it is for.

Based on your markup, you could do something like the following:

```
<div>
  <span class="badge">{{rowNumber}}</span>
  <div class="row">
    <a ng-repeat="item in items" class="col-xs-3">
      {{item.name}}
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `col-xs-3` class that I've added to your link signifies that each `a` will use 3 columns out of a 12 column grid. Since 3 divided by 12 equals 4, we will end up with 4 columns of equal width.

Comment: My challenge is, the number if items is variable. For that reason, I do not believe I can just use columns. Is there another way?

Comment: Do you want it to display evenly for any number of columns? So if you have 10 items it will be in 10 columns in one row, 8 items will have 8 columns in one row, etc.? Or can it go to multiple rows?

Comment: Correct. Everything will be a single row. I do not need (or want) to span multiple rows.